# Выводит в сообщение None

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, sqlite3

```
def get_top_surviveds(self, id):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("SELECT survived FROM `stats` WHERE user_id = ?", (id, )).fetchone()
            self.connection.commit()
```

```
bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Топ выживших\n Андрей - {0}\nВова - {1}\n Максим - {2}'.format(sql_lighter.get_top_surviveds(754651730), sql_lighter.get_top_surviveds(982543922), sql_lighter.get_top_surviveds(1720547162)), reply_markup=menu)
```

И тут выдаёт None

Comment: Ваша функция get_top_surviveds ничего не возвращает, оттого и получается None

Comment: Я использовал return к self.cursor.execute и к self.connection.commit()

Comment: Теперь выдаёт  <sqlite3.Row object at 0x000000000387AD10>

Comment: странно что курсор уже инициализирован, Вы его от подключения должны вызвать. `self.connection.cursor as cursor:` . Дальше выполнить `cursor.execute`, а потом вернуть `cursor.fetchone()` уже. commit тут не нужен